# How is a URL modified by more than one rewrite rule in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to ask a question in order to understand how Apache processes rewrite rules specified in the .htaccess file.

On my site I used a classical organization of the pages in categories, each category having more than one section:

```
http://www.mysite.com/category/section.html.
```

However, there are no html pages, everything is processed by the code in pages.php. Using a simple rewrite rule, URLs like the one above are mapped onto:

```
http://www.mysite.com/pages.php?cat=category&page=section
```

I decided to rename a section from **section1** to **section1-xxx**. In order to serve requests for the old name (section1), I added a simple rule to map **section1.html** on **section1-xxx.html**.

The first rules I added in the .htaccess were the following:

R1

```
RewriteRule ^CAT1/section1.html$ CAT1/section1-xxx.html [NC]
```

where **CAT1** is the name of a category.

R2

```
RewriteRule ^CAT1/(.*).html$ pages.php?cat=CAT1&page=$1 [L,NC]
```

My idea was to apply R1 and then R2. However, when those rules are applied, I end up with an unexplainable (for my brain) URL.

When the following page is requested

```
http://www.mysite.com/CAT1/section1.html
```

the URL is first transformed in

```
http://www.mysite.com/CAT1/section1-xxx.html/section1.html
```

then in

```
http://www.mysite.com/pages.php?cat=CAT1&page=section1-xxx.html/section1
```

Out of curiosity, I added the **L** (flag) to rule R1:

```
RewriteRule ^CAT1/section1.html$ CAT1/section1-xxx.html [L,NC]
```

and everything worked fine. Now http://www.mysite.com/CAT1/section1.html is served via:

```
http://www.mysite.com/pages.php?cat=CAT1&page=section1-xxx
```

Now the questions:

1. Why did I get that URL before adding the **L** flag to rule R1?
2. The **L** flag should indicate to apply the matching rule and then stop using other rules. However, with the **L** flag set, both **R1** and **R2** are applied. Why?

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
 A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [L] flag can have unexpected results if we are not clear on how the module behaves. Note that the following only applies when mod_rewrite is used in a .htaccess file. The [L] flag behaves exactly as expected when used in httpd.conf.

The L flag will tell Apache to stop processing the rewrite rules for that request. Now what is often unrealised is that it now makes a new request for the new, rewritten filename and begin processing the rewrite rules again.

Therefore, if you were to do a rewrite where the destination is still a match to the pattern, it will not behave as desired. In these cases, you should use a RewriteCond to exlude a certain file from the rule.

As you explained add L to R1.(R1 redirects something.html to someone.html ie you nedd html page their!)

Comment: Thanks very much for your very clear answer. Yesterday I read the manual and the rewrite log file, but it was too much to ingest in a single study session.

Answer (score 1):

1) you need the starting / in the substitution string in R1

2) as said by amolv, you have two iterations through the rewrite engine, in the first case both R1 and R2 matched, and the rewritten url matched no rules in the second iteration; adding L to R1, the incoming url matched just R1 in the first iteration and just R2 in the second. With the starting / in both R1 and R2, you dont need the L in R1 anymore.

I'd like to know the contents of that section "XXX" ;)

Comment: You would be disappointed: I used it just to attract readers ;-) Thanks for you answer.